# Makefile: change in dependencies fail to trigger rebuild

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile target that depends on a dynamic list of source files. This list is parsed on `make` invocations so it could potentially change. It looks like this:

```
target: $(shell cat foo.txt)
    @echo "build target"
```

`foo.txt` changes from time to time. What I'm seeing is that `target` will be rebuilt the first time `foo.txt` changes content to `X`. Say that `foo.txt` changes content to `Y` then changes back to `X` then `target` won't be built. I know I can include `foo.txt` as a dependency itself but for reasons difficult to explain that's not an option.

As a more concrete example, `foo.txt` looks like this:

```
google.golang.org/grpc@v1.29.0/dialoptions.go
```

but could change to something like:

```
google.golang.org/grpc@v1.28.0/dialoptions.go
```

What's going on? Is Makefile caching something?

---

EDIT

I guess Makefile is caching the timestamp of the dependencies and thus if the dependency files didn't change at all then the target won't be rebuilt? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make caches nothing.  It has no preserved data whatsoever about any previous build.  Make uses the filesystem as its "cache".

Because you're using `$(shell cat foo.txt)`, make knows absolutely nothing about the file `foo.txt`.  All it knows about is the set of files inside the `foo.txt` files.  It treats all of those as prerequisites.

Then it merely compares the time last modified of the target file (`target`) with the time last modified of the prerequisite file that is contained in `foo.txt`.

So if `foo.txt` contains `google.golang.org/grpc@v1.29.0/dialoptions.go` then it's as if your makefile was written to be:

```
target: google.golang.org/grpc@v1.29.0/dialoptions.go
```

and if the time last modified of `target` is *older* than `google.golang.org/grpc@v1.29.0/dialoptions.go` (use `ls -l` to see these values) then make decides `target` is out of date and must be rebuilt.  If it's newer, then make decides `target` is up to date and doesn't have to be rebuilt.

If you change the contents of `foo.txt` to be `google.golang.org/grpc@v1.28.0/dialoptions.go` then it compares the time last modified between `target` and `google.golang.org/grpc@v1.28.0/dialoptions.go`, the same way.

That's all make does, at its root.

I don't really understand your requirements so I can't give any suggestions for solutions.  If you need to have `target` rebuilt if *either* the contents of `foo.txt` changes *or* the modification time on the prerequisite listed in `foo.txt` changes, then the only way to do that is list `foo.txt` as a prerequisite so make can detect when it was changed.  You say you can't do that so... I don't have any good solutions for you.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks.